# $\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{x^n}$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits

$$\sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \frac{4^n}{x^n}$$
Determine the value of $x$ for

1. absolute convergence
2. conditional convergence
3. divergence

I have solved it by root test, what I can't figure is how to analyze for different values of $x$.

Also, can we use Lebnitz test to analyze $x=4,-4$, or does its failure not conclude divergence?

Comment: Hint: set $t:=4/x$.

Comment: You should insert that comment in the question.

Answer (score 1):

First, to get all of several letters as a superscript, put them In braces, {}: $\sum_0^{infinity}\frac{(4^n)}{(x^n)}$.  Better is to use "\infty": $\sum_0^\infty\frac{(4^n)}{(x^n)}$.

To answer your question, write $\frac{4^n}{x^n}$ as $\left(\frac{4}{x}\right)^n$.  Now you have $\sum_{n=0}^\infty\left(\frac{4}{x}\right)^n$, a "geometric series".
  It is well known that the sum of the geometric series $\sum_{n= 0}^\infty r^n$ is $\frac{1}{1- r}$ for |r|< 1 and that the series does not converge for |r|> 1.  So this series converges, absolutely, for $\left|\frac{4}{x}\right|< 1$, that is, for |x|> 4, to $\frac{1}{1-\frac{4}{x}}= \frac{x}{x- 4}$ and does not converge for |x|< 4.  (When x= 4, this is a infinite sum of "1"s so does not converge.  When x= -4, we have the alternating series 1-1+1-1+... which has "partial sums" 1, 0, 1, 0, 1,... so also does not converge.)

Comment: Thanks a lot! Can we use Lebnitz theorem to analyze x=4,-4 ; or does it's failure not conclude divergence?

Answer (score 0):

Hint: The finite sum is given by $$\sum_{n=0}^m\frac{4^n}{x^n}=-\frac{x-4^{m+1} x^{-m}}{4-x}$$ now compute the limit for $m$ tends to infinity.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{4^n}{x^n}=\left(\frac4x\right)^n=q^n$$
We get a geometrical series, which converges only for  $-1<q<1$.
$$
\frac4x>-1\implies x<-4\\
\frac4x<1\implies x>4
$$

The series diverges for $-4<x<4$